# Get compressed data from sql server database to wpf application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, mvvm

I have created an application in wpf, mvvm. I have used sql server database for this application.
When i run the application it communicate with the sql server and retrieve data.

My problem is that when database size is very large and I request for large data(35-40 mb) from it, it takes so much time (10-20 minutes)to get data.

Is there any way to get compressed data from server and reduce the network lag?

Comment: Can you show us the code in question?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One of the factor which is affecting the speed is...  type of Service/ Framework are you using to communicate with the database. Protocol buffer is one of that latest ones which enhance the speed. But it has some darwbacks too...

Comment: It is most likely lies with the way you are interfacing the data with SQL. As Mad Myche said, we need the code in question that you are using to get the data from the database and/or the framework you are using too.